# Is there a cleaner way to ensure I am not writing duplicate data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following loop which uses Idiorm to write to a table from a PHP Slim application:

```
foreach($jobs->get_items() as $job) {

        echo $job->get_title().'<br />';
        $jobRow = ORM::for_table('jobs')->create();
        $jobRow->guid = $job->get_id(TRUE);
        $jobRow->url = $job->get_link();
        $jobRow->description = $job->get_description();
        $jobRow->pubdate = $job->get_date();
        echo $job->get_date();

        try {
        $jobRow->save();
        } catch (exception $e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

It feels a bit hacky to be using continue in a try/ catch block. Is there a better way to avoid a MYSQL constraint violation without having to query the table? get_id() returns an md5 hash of the guid in an rss feed which is actually a unqiue URL. I have a UNIQUE index on that field in my table.

Answer (score 1):

How exceptional is this error? What do you want to do when this happens?

If it's rare and you don't want to do anything, then:

- Only catch the actual exception (maybe it's `PDOException`).
- Remove the `continue` which serves no purpose here and could confuse the reader.
- Make sure you don't fail silently when the error is not a violation error.

Your code will look like this:

```
try {
    $jobRow->save();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if(!isAnExpectedViolation()) {
        // I still need to do something about it!
    }
}
```

If it's really frequent, you may want to check if it's going to violate the constraint before running the query. If it's frequent and you want to tell about it to the user, put it into an `if` and act accordingly.

Comment: Note that you don't need to agree on the "exceptions are exceptional" policy, but it's important not to catch every kind of exception that could be thrown.

Comment: Just getting round to looking at this again. The exception will happen alot as the data is coming from a feed which may well have duplicates of existing data. I'm hashing a URL to generate a guid and if there is a row with the same hash the exception will get thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You really really REALLY don't want to hide errors like this.  It will come back to haunt you when in 18 months you're asked to update the script or debug it and you do something that triggers an error condition but nothing to alert you to the fact ever happens.

I've had many jobs where debugging some code was made far harder than it needed to be because someone had tried to just sweep errors under the carpet with an @ operator or by catching an exception and doing nothing with it.

I know that doesn't answer your question.  But I thought it was important to point that out.